# Spring boot Data @Transactional not working when calling a MSSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I'm having some issues while trying to call a stored procedure from the code (not sure if it helps but it's basically some selects and inserts).

This is what I have so far:

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Inserter {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveAndCommit(Mapper mapper) {
       saveAll(...)
       ...
       softDeletes(mapper, this.containerRepository);
    }

    private <T, N> void saveAll(JpaRepository<T, N> repository, List<T> entityList) {
        if (entityList != null && !entityList.isEmpty()) {
            repository.saveAll(entityList);
        }
    }

    private void softDeletes(Mapper mapper, ContainerRepository containerRepository) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And what I have in softDeletes is a few stored procedure calls like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "EXEC SP_Soft_Deletes '...', '...', :state_container_id, :parent_id, :transaction_id, '...', :last_modification", nativeQuery = true)
void generateSoftDeletes(
    @Param("...") String ...,
    @Param("...") String ...,
    @Param("...") String ...,
    @Param("last_modification") LocalDateTime last_modification
);
```

When softDeletes is called, I get the following exception:

`Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

Apparently, saveAndCommit is not creating one transaction for all those methods but I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Thank you!